# Python multithread per block

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm executing the following Python code, but when I launch many threads the remote API (Google API) returns:

```
 <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/prediction/v1.6/projects/project/trainedmodels/return_reason?alt=json returned "User Rate Limit Exceeded">
```

I have around 20K objects which I need to launch at a time to be processed by API. This works fine with small amount of objects, how to slow down or send request by blocs ?

```
from threading import *

collection_ = []
lock_object = Semaphore(value=1)

def connect_to_api(document):
    try:
        api_label = predictor.make_prediction(document)
        return_instance = ReturnReason(document=document) # Create Return Reason Object
        lock_object.acquire()                             # Lock object
        collection_.append(return_instance)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
    finally:
        lock_object.release()

def factory():
    """

    :return:
    """

    list_of_docs = file_reader.get_file_documents(file_contents)
    threads = [Thread(target=connect_to_api, args=(doc,)) for doc in list_of_docs]
    [t.start() for t in threads]
    [t.join() for t in threads]
```

Comment: Use a threadpool. Your request is a standard task, there's nothing special about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rate processing is a whole problem, probably just a sleep will not be enought for long term tasks.

I suggest you to look into queues (rq is pretty simple) and also following article will be helpful: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/70/